# What caused Stack Overflow to display the "Works Best With JavaScript Enabled" Banner this past hour?

Tags: support, user-experience

I've been on SO for a little over six years and I have tailored my JavaScript settings to allow Stack Overflow full JavaScript privileges, but do not, and will not, provide the same authority to tracking sites or sites unnecessary to the operation of Stack Overflow. My current JavaScript settings are:

[image]

I have changed nothing on my end, but about 30 minutes ago and big pink banner claiming "Stack Overflow Works Better with JavaScript Enabled" (or similar) splashed across the top of the page.

Was there a change that prompted the banner? If so, will it affect how SO works going forward compared to how it has operated in the past?

Comment: Does the banner still appear after disabling your extensions? I have the same 4 domains blocked (by hosts file, not by an adblocker) and don't see the banner. Does anyone else see the banner?

Comment: Next time you see it happen, open your browser console (control-shift-i) and look for errors. It sounds like a resource didn't load as expected - it may well be listed there. (Ignore GA, quantserve, and scorecardresearch - the issue is somewhere else)

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, I had 2 tabs open in Firefox 68.11 and the banner appeared in both tabs at the same time. I was away from the computer for about 30 minutes and the banners were both present when I returned. I'll open the developer console the next time it occurs.

Comment: Could have been triggered as the result of an ad running on the page. Some ads are very invasive. When was the last time Firefox updated with relation to your observation?

Comment: Something definitely changed, The "Related" Questions are missing from all questions on SO now. It skips from the "The Overflow Blog" box (with space still left for where the "Related" links should be) to "Hot Network Questions" with nothing but blank space in between. So there has been a change that is making parts of the page not show up.